# What's the capitalization rule for tabulated entries?

Tags: capitalization, writing-style

Do I have to capitalize each cell in a table, or only be consistent throughout the table?

Answer (score 3):

There is no universal rule for formatting the entries in individual cells of a table; capitalization of those entries is strictly a style issue.

I checked three widely respected style guides (*Chicago Manual of Style*, *Oxford Style Manual*, and *Words Into Type*), and none of them has anything to say on this particular point. At the magazines where I've worked, the house style was to lowercase single-word and short-phrase cell entries, and to initial-cap (and end-punctuate) sentence-length entries. Nevertheless, this was strictly an in-house style decision; I've seen many instances where table cell entries are initial-capped even if they consist of a single word like *Yes* or *No*.

Both within a table and across multiple tables (if applicable), consistency is important, since it helps readers negotiate the sometimes challenging presentation of ideas that a complex or very succinct table may entail. *Chicago*, fifteenth edition (2003) has this to say on that point:

> **13.69** *Consistency.* However neat and orderly a table may appear, it must be checked not only internal consistency but for conformity to the text and to other tables in the same work. Column heads and stubs [entries in the leftmost column of the table] must match one another in style across a series of tables. Spelling, capitalization, punctuation, abbreviations, and symbols must likewise be regularized.

Answer (score 1):

This might be better answered on the [User Experience SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com) site. The general rule is "consistency": capitalize everything consistently.

Comment: I was refering to a printed report, not an app, but I guess it's the same :)